Issues Receiving Multicast UDP Data with Mellanox Network Card in C++ on Windows
I am working on a C++ application to receive multicast UDP data on a Windows machine. I have encountered an issue where the application is missing data packets when using a Mellanox network card. However, the same application works perfectly with a Solarflare network card.
Setup:
Windows operating system.
Mellanox network card.
Multicast UDP receiver written in C++.
The same machine also has Wireshark installed.
Observations:
When I use Wireshark to join the multicast group and receive data from the Mellanox card, no data packets are missing.
When I run my C++ application to receive multicast data on the Mellanox card, it misses some data packets.
The same C++ application works fine with a Solarflare network card, receiving all data packets without any loss.
Code snippet :
// Initialize Winsock
WSADATA wsaData;
int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (result != 0) {
    std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << result << std::endl;
    return;
}

// Create socket
SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (fd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cerr << "socket creation failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Allow multiple sockets to use the same port number
BOOL yes = TRUE;
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&yes, sizeof(yes)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "setsockopt SO_REUSEADDR failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    closesocket(fd);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Set receive buffer size
int receiveBufferSize = 655360000; // 250 * 1024 * 1024;
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (const char*)&receiveBufferSize, sizeof(receiveBufferSize)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "setsockopt SO_RCVBUF failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    closesocket(fd);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Bind to the specified interface and port
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(_interface.c_str());
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    closesocket(fd);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Join the multicast group
ip_mreq mreq{};
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(group.c_str());
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(_interface.c_str());
if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (const char*)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "setsockopt IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    closesocket(fd);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

LOG_INFO << "Successfully created socket IP: " << group << ", PORT: " << port << " & INTERFACE: " << _interface;

// Main receiving loop
while (true) {
    char msgbuf[max_length];
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    int nbytes = recvfrom(fd, msgbuf, max_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);

    if (nbytes == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "recvfrom failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(fd);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Process received packet
    char* ptr = new char[nbytes];
    memcpy(ptr, msgbuf, nbytes);

    FIN_STRUCT queueMsg;
    queueMsg.msg = ptr;
    queueMsg.len = nbytes;
    multicast_q.push(queueMsg);
}

What could be causing my C++ application to miss data packets when using the Mellanox network card?
Are there any specific configurations or optimizations needed for Mellanox cards to handle multicast traffic efficiently in a C++ application on Windows?
Why does Wireshark not miss any packets while my C++ application does?
Any suggestions or troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I have tried change the recive buffer on the mellonox card .
Same mellonox card is working on the linux machine
I did change widows receive buffer but nothing works
Is there any document available on mellnox support for windows
Or does any one already worked with the mellnox with windows os

Have you tried pre-allocating the packet buffers? What is multicast_q? What happens when it is full? Is anything pulling from that queue? If so, is it keeping up with traffic?

@jisrael18 Thanks for reply . I tried with the preallocation buffer . multicast_q is thread safe queue . Another thread is processing the data from the queue . Yes it is keeping up with the traffic . No i never seen that queue is getting full . Same application is working fine with solarflare card but not with mellonox
